# Trying to store and filter an object and want to pass for post service in Redux. cannot store value properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

here is a case,      filterName = Year, filterItem = [2019,2018,2017];

right now i am storing in filterComponies = [2019,2018,2017], but i want to store and pass as filtercomponies = {Year: ["2019", "2018", "2017"]},{another object same as year}

```
case 'UPDATE_FILTERS': {
  let updateFilterCompanies = [];    
  if (action.filterName === 'YEAR') {
    const filterComponies = [...state.filterComponies];
    if (filterComponies.find((fil) => fil === action.filterItem)) {
      updateFilterCompanies = filterComponies.filter((fil) => fil !== action.filterItem);
    } else {
      updateFilterCompanies = [...filterComponies,action.filterItem];
    }
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    formCardList: data.formCardList,
    filterComponies: updateFilterCompanies
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid object `{"Year":"2019","2018","2017"}`. Do you mean something more like this: `{Year: ["2019", "2018", "2017"]}` ?

Comment: Yeah, that could work aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
case 'UPDATE_FILTERS': {
    if (action.filterName === 'YEAR') {
        return {
            ...state,
            formCardList: data.formCardList,
            filterComponies: {
                ...state.filterComponies,
                Year: action.filterItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 4 more IF conditions in same case, all object stores into an array of filterComponies. So i cant return like that. Plus, if i put Year before action, it will give me Year:2019, Year:2018. I have to send Year: [2019,2018]